# Почему action от mobx не работает в useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, action, mobx, useeffect

Есть код:

```
useEffect(()=>{
         fetch(ServerURLS.ALL, {method:'GET'}).then((response)=>response.json()).then((response)=> {
            // action(()=>{store.todoStore.toDoList = response}) не работает
            store.todoStore.toDoList = response; // работает но с warning
        })
    }
    ,[filter])
```

Почему action (изменение стора) не работает? Без него все работает но в консоли предупреждение, что так делать не нужно и нужно обработать изменение стора через action. Что может быть не так?

Comment: Возможно надо просто написать так: `action(result);`, т.е. просто передать полученное значение для сохранения его в состоянии стора

Comment: А как он тогда поймет какое поле стора ему менять? Да и экшн принимает функцию

Comment: Если это аналог redux, то должно быть что то вида `action({type: 'addToDoList', data: result})` где `'addToDoList'` это собственно событие, в котором уже указывается, что обновлять

Comment: Нет, это не аналог. Там в экшн передаётся не объект

Comment: @SwaD, `mobx` вообще не аналог ` redux`, там такое организовывать - только все усложнять. Принцип там такой - класс. Свойства это собственно хранилище данных. Методы его меняют. Вычисляемые методы показывают данные в нужном свете...

Answer (score 0):

Для корректной записи асинхронных данных можно использовать два пути.

Cделать обычный `mobx` метод, передать ему полученные данные. Он их запишет в стейт

```
loadWeather = city => {
  fetch(
    'https://abnormal-weather-api.herokuapp.com/cities/search?city=' + city
  )
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.setWeatherData(data);
    });
};

setWeatherData = data => {
  this.weatherData = data;
};
```

Использовать `runInAction()`

```
import { runInAction } from "mobx";

// ...

loadWeatherRunInThen = city => {
  fetch('https://abnormal-weather-api.herokuapp.com/cities/search?city=' + city)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      runInAction(() => {
        this.weatherData = data;
      });
    });
};
```

Есть даже третий вариант! Использовать `flow` от `mobx`.

```
import { flow } from 'mobx'

const apiUrl = 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees'

class EmployeeService {
    getEmployees = () => {
        return fetch(apiUrl).then((response) => response.json())
    }

    getEmployeesAsyncAwait = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(apiUrl)
        const data = await response.json()
        return data
    }

    getEmployeesGenerator = flow(function* () {
        const response = yield fetch(apiUrl)
        const data = yield response.json()
        return data
    })
}

export default EmployeeService
```